# How would you design a code legal guard railing on a raised block deck that also has a 22" high block bench that runs along the deck perimeter?

Tags: code-compliance, deck, brick, railing, cinderblock

In December a contractor built a raised masonry block deck with a wall/bench on top.  I didn't plan the job well, so now I'm planning for 37' of guardrail.  I would prefer the guardrail didn't hide the wall/bench because the blocks are pretty cool looking, and I don't want the guardrail mounted on top of the wall/bench because I'll lose seating space which is only 12" deep.

I have to design a 37' long guard rail system for less than $5000, and I'm not very handy.  I like the idea of custom wrought iron or aluminum, but it's probably too expensive.  I could also install a big box aluminum kit or buy all the aluminum components separately to give me flexibility.  I could also install a wooden railing.  I live in a rural area with no contractors so custom components would come from a city 2 hours away.

A code legal guard rail has to be at least 36" high off the deck.  The block bench also serves as a wall but is only 22" high above the deck.  The bench was built 7" in from the edge of the deck, but I only have about 4" of usable space for the posts.

I'm looking into custom wrought iron with 36" high posts with the bottom rail 22" high off the deck.  The balusters (AKA pickets?) would be 14" long (36-22).  The bottom rail would be that high so the balusters didn't obscure the block bench.

I understand that if I buy a kit or separate components that I'd have to cut the balusters to 14" myself.  Thanks.

[image: Wall Bench Showing 7 inch Ledge]
[image: Front View of Raised Deck]

Comment: Do you want the guardrail or do you think you need the guardrail? I ask because often a deck under a certain height is not required to have rails.

Comment: Could just leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

See [IRC R312.1.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch03_SecR312.1.1) for whether guards are required. If the walking surface is higher than 30" above the surrounding grade, then they're required.

When guards are required, they're relatively ugly because of [IRC R312.1.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch03_SecR312.1.3). R312.1.3 requires that a 4" sphere cannot fit through the guardrail anywhere below the 36" rail height. I guess it's so that kids can't get their heads stuck in there.

If you're barely breaking that 30" maximum height requirement from R312.1.1, then consider regrading the surrounding area to avoid the ugly guard rails. Even if you want the rails, avoiding the 4" sphere requirement will allow a much more attractive outcome.